# List in Python Does Not Maintain Values When Use Replace Method

Tags: python, list, recursion, replace

So, I wrote this code that takes in a file (in my case, a bunch of trump tweets). Then, I enter a loop where I thought I could recursively continue to deform these tweets by replacing key words at a time (e.g. "Russia" instead of "America" for Make America Great Again). However, the list does not maintain the replaced values; so, if I make one replacement the old replacements are erased. How do I continue to deform this text, one step at a time, within this loop?

```
load_text = raw_input("filename: ")
f = open(load_text)

text = []
for line in f:
    text.append(line)

loop = 1
while loop == 1:

    replace_this = raw_input("replace this: ")
    with_this = raw_input("with this: ")

    for line in text:
        line = line.replace(replace_this, with_this)
        print line
```

Comment: You're reassigning `line`, not the list element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `line` is reassigned when you do `line = line.replace(replace_this, with_this)`, it does not actually update the contents of `text`. To assign the actual line within `text` you can do something like:

```
for idx, line in enumerate(text):
    text[idx] = line.replace(replace_this, with_this)
    print text[idx]
```

Comment: Upvoted for using `enumerate` properly, instead of demonstrating the `for i in range(len(someseq)):` anti-pattern. :-)

Comment: OK; this is awesome. Thank you; will research enumerate now.

Answer (score 0):

Access the explicit list element instead with the following loop

```
for i in range (len(text)):
    text[i] = text[i].replace(replace_this, with_this)
    print(text[i])
```